# TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of null

Tags: javascript, pentaho, indexof, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm triying to find the records that includes "SO -" or "NS - SO" or "SO –" or "SWAT" on THE "RESUMEN" field from a CSV file to asigne a new category (in this cases would be "Call Center"). So, I used "indexOf" funtion witch worked so well.

The problem comes when I change the data source (It is a CSV too), this gave me next error on that step: 
"Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of null (script#2)"

The objective is to assign a category by identifying the words on the source file

My code

```
if (RESUMEN.indexOf("SO -")!=-1 || RESUMEN.indexOf("NS - SO")!=-1 || RESUMEN.indexOf("SO –" )!=-1 || RESUMEN.indexOf("SWAT")!=-1)
{
var RESULTADO = "Call Center"
}
else RESULTADO = ""
```

I expect to assigne call center category like I got with the first file (I did not change nothing)

regards!

Comment: Obviously `RESUMEN` is null, so run a check `if (RESUMEN)` before doing anything

Comment: Are you sure your RESUMEN variable is set? Try to log it to the console to see what it prints, if it prints null then there you have it.

Comment: It could be declared as something like this: 
const RESUMEN = null;
and then you forgot to change its value

Comment: @SuperSimplePimpleDimple there is no point in logging it out because we already know its value is null.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Yes but some people get confused and dont understand error messages. This way he will see that the variable he is trying to access the indexOf property is null. 

Ive seen so many questions asking for answers to errors like "cannot access some property of undefined/null".

Comment: Can you show the code where you assign a value to `RESUMEN`? As others have said, it's clearly `null`, but from your question it sounds like it's not supposed to be.

Comment: In fact, thats all the code that assign the value to "RESUMEN" when the record has that characters that I've already mentioned in the top, the new var ("RESULTADO") would be named "Call Center" in the other hand would be "Null" (easy pisi). Now, in my data (input) there is not a null record in all the rows from "RESUMEN" field. Actually there are that kind of characters that I need but the error persist

Comment: @AlanGutiérrez You aren't assigning a value to `RESUMEN` anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I know it, I'm assigning a value in a new variable wich is "RESULTADO" . "RESUMEN" keeps the same. 
The value from "RESULTADO" depends from the "RESUMEN" field

Comment: @AlanGutiérrez But your problem is that `RESUMEN` doesn't have a value. So we can't fix it without seeing where that value is supposed to come from.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating the issue.

Before the answer, remember something, there are several steps, and combinations of steps, that achieve an incredible number of transformations to make usable patterns, **the last resort IS User defined Java Expression.**

Seems like what you want to achieve is a Value Mapping, thou the difference from a direct value map in your case, is that the row you're testing must contain "SO -", and the other cases, somewhere in the text.

[image]

With this simple filter, you can transform your data that contains those informations as you desire, and on the "FALSE" side, treat it for errors.

This will expand your transformation a bit, but when you need to change something it will be easier than with a single step with a lot of code.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to address the problem he has (getting a `null` result from the CSV).

Comment: it does, in that this step achieves the same result, without throwing an error on nulls.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer pointed out, you can achieve the same result with different steps, you don't need the javascript step.

But, if you want to go that route, you should first convert null values into, e.g., empty strings.

Simply add this to the beginning of your javascript code:

`if (!RESUMEN){ RESUMEN = ''}`

That'll convert nulls to empty strings and then `indexOf` returns correctly.